# Chrome extension is not runing auto. Content scripts not executing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am experimenting with Google Chrome Extensions and first problems I have is that I want to automaticly change body background color when page is loaded (without clicking on extension icon) but my content scripts are not firing up:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "Testing",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "webNavigation"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Set this page's color.",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "js": ["core.js"]
  }
  ],  
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**core.js:**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";'});
```

Not working solution **background.js:**

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"core.js"});
});
```

Where is the problem? Please for help.

Comment: look at the documentation on how to write a content script.  core.js is where the code goes, not tbrough excutescript.

Comment: just write : window.onload=function(){ document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; } instead executeScript in your core.js file

Comment: I have done it and it seems core.js is not running...

Comment: @Edenwave Why not ? where  and what you try ? I try this and it's work for me

Comment: I changed code of core.js to one you typed in your last answer. Core is not executing and I don't know why.

Comment: Something write in the console ? on which website you try ? try to console.log something in additon to the change color and check again : window.onload=function(){ 
    console.log("test!");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; }

Comment: Console.log is not executing, like all the core.js file... :C

Comment: @Edenwave I post my code that work for me , try it .

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: What *exactly* is shown in the [various appropriate consoles for your extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982/3773011) when you load and execute your extension? Based on your code, you should have gotten some specific errors which would have helped inform you as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better solution's for you it's just use the content script and to wait until load and not execute script:

manifest.json

```
 {
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "Testing",
   "version": "1.0",
   "permissions": [
     "tabs", "webNavigation"
   ],
   "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Set this page's color.",
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
   "content_scripts": [
   {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["core.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   }
 ],  
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

core.js

```
  window.onload=function(){ 
   console.log("test!!");
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; }
```

popup.html no matter here.
I just try it and it's work in change the background color to green in any site (you could try on stackoverflow)  and console also.

Comment: I really don't know why, but now it is working... Thank you OriEng.